# Choosing PHP version for a Heroku app

Tags: php, heroku

I deployed an app to Heroku and it correctly detected that it was a PHP app. It works great, but there's a small issue. Heroku chose to use PHP version 5.3, and I'd like to use version 5.4.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: PHP support on Heroku is now official and you can choose your preferred PHP version simply from the [composer.json](https://github.com/delight-im/Heroku-PHP-Apache2/blob/master/composer.json) file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several unofficial buildpacks that use more modern PHP versions, here's an example that uses PHP 5.4 and has several other improvements: https://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler

To use:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler.git
```

... and push a new build.

Comment: I run your command on my project folder, and I got this output:

`Setting config vars and restarting juampi... done, v19
BUILDPACK_URL: git://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler.git`

However, the PHP version seems to still be 5.3, as you can see here: http://www.juampi.com/test.php

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You have to re-deploy after setting `BUILDPACK_URL`.